# Ruby templating engine Slim block confusion

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, slim-lang

I am new to slim and I find it a bit confusing.. so I have this code

```
td Tags: == item.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t,tag_path(t) }.join(', ')
```

I am having this output

`<td tags:="#<Enumerator:0xbb6e8b4>">{ |t| link_to t,tag_path(t) }.join(', ') </td>`

Basically I want the output to be "Tags: tag1,tag2,tag3"

How to get out of the td tag in slim?

edit:

Added a bit more code:

```
-@items.each do |item|
 tr
   td = item.title
   td = item.description
   td = item.price
   td = item.user.username
   td = item.categories.map { |c| c.name  }.join{', '}  
   - if params[:user_id].nil?
     td = link_to 'Show', item_path(item)
   - else
     td = link_to 'Show', edit_user_item_path(@user,item)
     td = link_to 'Edit', edit_user_item_path(@user,item)
     td = link_to 'Destroy', user_item_path(@user,item), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } 
     td Tags: == item.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t,tag_path(t) }.join(', ')
```

edit: I tried this

```
- tags = item.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t,tag_path(t) }.join(', ').html_safe 
td = "Tags: #{tags}"
```

but now html_safe is not working so I have this output

```
Tags:&lt;a href="/tag/tag3"&gt;tag3&lt;/a&gt;, &lt;a href="/tag/tag2"&gt;tag2&lt;/a&gt;, &lt;a href="/tag/tag1"&gt;tag1&lt;/a&gt;
```

Comment: this `.join{', '}` just a typo? and please fix indentation like in you view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own problem here is what I did

```
- tags = item.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t,tag_path(t) }.join(', ').html_safe 
 <td>Tags: #{tags}</td>
```

Got it working now like it supposed to.